# How to transpile ECMA6 import of jQuery to a UMD wrapper with Babel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, babeljs, umd

I'm trying to use Babel to transpile ECMA6 import of jQuery to a UMD wrapper.

My ECMA6 sources look as follows:

```
import {jQuery as $} from jquery;

<payload>
```

and Babel transpiles this to:

```
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    var mod = {
      exports: {}
    };
    factory(global.jquery);
    global.metisMenu = mod.exports;
  }
})(this, function (_jquery) {
  'use strict';

  var _jquery2 = _interopRequireDefault(_jquery);

  function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
      default: obj
    };
  }

  var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) {
    return typeof obj;
  } : function (obj) {
    return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj;
  };

  function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
      throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
    }
  }

  <payload>(_jquery.jQuery);

  })
```

This code works fine in Node.js environment as `require('jquery')` takes jquery from `node_modules`.

However, in browser environment `global.jquery` (which is equivalent to `window.jquery`) is not defined - jquery imports itself as `$` or `jQuery`, but not as `jquery`.

Are there any Babel settings to fix this?

My current `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["env", {
            "modules": "umd",
            "loose": true
        }]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `globals` option in the `transform-es2015-modules-umd` plugin:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-es2015-modules-umd", {
      "globals": {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

See the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-umd/#usage).